# Text to speech Manager doesn't work

Tags: android, voice, speech, text-to-speech

I created some TTS Manager, because I want use `someTTsObject.speak("some string")` in other classes.
This is my Manager class:

```
public class TtsManager
{
private TextToSpeech myTTS;
private Context context;

public TtsManager(Context baseContext)
{
    this.context = baseContext;
    initOrInstallTts();
}

public void initOrInstallTts()
{
    myTTS = new TextToSpeech(context, new OnInitListener() 
    {               
        public void onInit(int status) 
        {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
            {
                myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            }
            else
                installTts();
        }
    });
}

private void installTts()
{
    Intent installIntent = new Intent();
    installIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
    context.startActivity(installIntent);
}

public void speak(String text)
{       
        myTTS.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}

}
```

and this is my main class, where I want to use that:

```
public class main extends Activity {
TtsManager tts;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tts = new TtsManager(this);
        tts.speak("Welcome in my app");

    }
}
```

When I run compilation I see on the LogCat:

```
08-30 17:25:52.531: I/TTS received:(2782): Welcome in my app
```

but i don't hear any text. I tested it on the virtual machine and phone.

Why that doesn't work? 
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem is that you are not waiting until the callback comes from the system telling you the TTS is initialized.  You can't call speak until onInit is called with a SUCCESS value.

Answer (score 0):

problem is that you are calling speak function without initializing tts engine....
add
    **tts.initOrInstallTts();**
after
    **tts = new TtsManager(this);**

Like:

```
public class main extends Activity {
    TtsManager tts;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tts = new TtsManager(this);
    tts.initOrInstallTts();
    tts.speak("Welcome in my app");

    }
}
```